# Drupal 6: Group multiple values in tpl.php

Tags: drupal, date, view

When using the date and views module, you can specify in views (using row style fields) 'group multiple values'. Which is default on.

If you turn it off, you get multiple nodes each with a date. For example:
- 24th March ------- node1
- 25th March ------- node1

What I'm trying to figure out is: what if you are not using fields but node as Row style. How do you implement this not-group-multiple-values in your type-node.tpl.php?

---

edit - more details

when using the views and date module, you can choose group multiple values to group for example multiple dates that are in 1 node.

However I choose not to use the fields in the views module but to create my own type-node.tpl.php (by choosing node instead of fields as row style) . in following example I create 1 node with 2 dates in it:

node1 = date1: 25march + date2: 26march

I receive in the tpl.php node1 2 times. Once with 25march and once with 26march . What I would like to have is to receive node1 only one time, containing both dates in the date field.

I hope this explains the problem a bit more in detail.

Answer (score 0):

So your view results are essentially returning duplicates of the same node? From your description, it sounds like this is because your view is perhaps using a relationship that joins on node revisions and nodes that have been edited multiple times are the dupe. Changing the relationship to use a field from the node (not node revision) should help eliminate the duplicates. Sorry if I misunderstood the question, but it is not very detailed.

Comment: 1 node with 2 dates
if you print them out in the node.tpl.php you put in $node->field_date[0].["view"] .
However that is only 1 of the 2 dates that is in the node. 

Question: how do you get the same node again but with the other date ($node->field_date[1].["view"])